# How to use UTC, while defining model with prisma.js and in generals in express.js project

Tags: node.js, express, utc, prisma

How can I Run `node.js` project in UTC instead of local timezone?
and
How can I use UTC, when I want to define a model with `prisma.js`?

```
model Profile {
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())    // but I need UTC
  ModifiedDate DateTime? @updatedAt        // but I need UTC
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prisma automatically stores the date passed in UTC by default. Nothing extra needs to be added.